# How to modify preferences from a CheckBox view?

Tags: android, checkbox, preferences

My app has 3 steps to set it up for the first time.

In each of these steps I want the user to be able to modify preferences, since it's not a PreferenceScreen I cannot add a CheckBoxPreference.

I tried using a CheckBox view, however I don't know how to make it affect preferences.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a boolean value to your preferences like this:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(prefs == null)
        return;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    if(editor == null)
        return;

    editor.putBoolean("prefs_key_for_your_boolean", someBoolean);

    editor.commit();
```

and load it like this:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(prefs == null)
        return;

    someBoolean = prefs.getBoolean("prefs_key_for_your_boolean", defaultBooleanValue);
```

Read the value out of the checkbox view like this when you want to save it:

```
    someBoolean = checkBoxView.isChecked();
```

And set it using the value you loaded from the prefs like this:

```
    checkBoxView.setChecked(someBoolean);
```

You can listen for changes to the checkbox state like this:

```
    checkBoxView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // add code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks @samgak, I should use an onclick listener for changes right? also could I make a custom view that's a child of CheckBox and implement some of this code?

Comment: @lisovaccaro see edit for how to listen for changes. You could make a custom view but it's not necessary, you can just put this code in your Activity.